# Using strong parameters require as 'required form attributes' validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One person in my team proposed to use ActionController::Parameters#require method to validate that the user submits the 'required' inputs in the form.

For me, it doesn't fit well, as you've got to handle errors separately from ActiveRecord models (presence: true).

So, for instance, let's say we have a user with :name, :age and :zip_code. And :name and :age are required.

He wants something like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).require(:name)
  params.require(:user).require(:age)
  params.require(:user).permit(:zip_code)
end
```

For me, it seems like Strong Parameters is not designed for this purpose and model validations like `presence: true` it's much more clean.

What do you consider a good practice? Why using one and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

Model validation is a completely different from this. You have model validation to implement what values are permitted on a field, what are the mandatory fields, etc... It's more in terms of the business logic. But, strong parameters are a security measure.

Strong parameters are there to prevent users from updating unwanted fields in the database. It's a security measure so that the application decides which fields can be updated in the database. For an example, if you have name, age, zip_code and login_attempt in your table. The login_attempt is there to count the number of failed login attempts. When you don't have strong parameters and you save the user changes as follows,

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

The user can easily update the login_attempt field as well. Inorder to prevent this rails has strong parameters. So, you are not vulnerable anymore for updating unwanted fields to the table. When you try to update fields that are not allowed you get this ForbiddenAttributesError. The correct way to do this is as follows,

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :zip_code)
end

@user = User.new(allowed_params)
@user.save
```